# Setting up a multisite wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to setup my wordpress installation with [multsite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) support and it's having issues resolving the domain.
I followed the steps but I did not change the domain from the initial ip address during setup.

So, I changed the settings in the `wp-config.php` file as follows:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '111.111.111.111');
```

to

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.mydomain.com');
```

and refreshed the page.

I am now getting a blank page when I try to access the site from `mydomain.com` but can still accesss the site through the ip address.

There is no actual setting to change the root domain in a wordpress multisite that I can see.

Any ideas why I am getting a blank page when I access my site from the domain name?

Here's my wp-config.php file:

```
<?php
/** custom settings */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
$base = '/';
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mydomain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

...
?>
```

Comment: This site is for programmers.  May I suggest you ask your question on wordpress.stackexchange.com? It'll likely be better received there....

Comment: Wordpress goes blank normally when there is any type of syntax area. My guess would be that the additions you made are not correct. If you add your wp-config file, we can go through it, but without anything to go off of it is hard to say where the problem is.

Comment: If you remove those lines can you get to the site? You mention resolving the domain name but that is handled by DNS. Try this https://wpengine.com/support/how-to-change-a-multi-site-primary-domain/